# Parcelized sealed class with private constructor throws inaccessible error when getting from Intent in new activity but works everywhere else?

Tags: kotlin

I made a special sealed class to validate my nullable URLs so I can safely and easily know it's state (None, Invalid, Valid)

```
sealed class UrlType : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize class Valid private constructor(val url: String) : UrlType() {
        companion object : CompanionTest<UrlType.Valid, String>(::Valid)
    }

    @Parcelize object None : UrlType()
    @Parcelize class Invalid(val invalidUrl: String) : UrlType()

    companion object {

        fun getUrlType(url: String?): UrlType {
            return if (url == null) {
                UrlType.None
            } else if (!url.isValidUrl()) {
                UrlType.Invalid(url)
            } else {
                Valid.create(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
open class CompanionTest<out T, in A>(creator: (A) -> T) {

    private var creator: ((A) -> T)? = creator

    fun create(arg1: A): T {
        return creator!!(arg1)
    }
}
```

---

```
@Parcelize
data class NewsPost(
        val id: String,
        val title: String,
        val description: String?,
        val webContentUrl: UrlType,
        val imageUrl: UrlType,
        val created: String,
        val updated: String,
        val feeds: List<Feed>
) : Parcelable
```

When I was first trying out the idea, I had my suspicions that it wouldn't work because of the private constructor and Parcelize but I did some tests and it did work.

I also have a sealed class to indicate a launch type for my activity which can be entered from multiple paths

```
sealed class NewsLaunchType : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize object FeedList : NewsLaunchType()
    @Parcelize class FeedDetail(val newsFeedType: NewsFeedType) : NewsLaunchType()
    @Parcelize class PostDetail(val newsPost: NewsPost) : NewsLaunchType()
}
```

When I go to launch my activity with a `NewsLaunchType.PostDetail(newsPost)` the app is crashing with the following error

```
fun startActivity(){
    val intent = Intent(context, NewsActivity::class.java).apply {                      
      putExtra("key", NewsLaunchType.PostDetail(newsPost))
    }      
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

---

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        val newsActivityLaunchType = intent.getParcelableExtra<NewsLaunchType>("key")
}
```

---

```
2018-11-08 11:08:33.897 17030-17030/com.something.internal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.something.internal, PID: 17030
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void com.something.somethingkit.helper.UrlType$Valid.<init>(java.lang.String)' is inaccessible to class 'com.something.somethingkit.helper.UrlType$Valid$Creator' (declaration of 'com.something.somethingkit.helper.UrlType$Valid$Creator' appears in /data/app/com.something.internal-QTiupS4yw25rZK5uXP7UCQ==/base.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.something.somethingkit.helper.UrlType$Valid$Creator.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:11)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2798)
        at com.something.somethingkit.model.news.local.NewsPost$Creator.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:25)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2798)
        at com.something.screens.news.NewsLaunchType$PostDetail$Creator.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2798)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2692)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3059)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:888)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7734)
        at com.something.screens.news.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Now that's not entirely unexpected, except that it does work if I try to pull it out within the same location I created it in

```
 fun startActivity(){
        val intent = Intent(context, NewsActivity::class.java).apply {                      
          putExtra("key", NewsLaunchType.PostDetail(newsPost))
        }      

        val test = intent.getParcelableExtra<NewsLaunchType>("key")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

It also works if I add it to a fragment bundle, and add/replace a new fragment into my activity.

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(newsPost: NewsPost): NewsDetailFragment {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelable(extraNewsPost, newsPost)

                val fragment = NewsDetailFragment()
                fragment.arguments = bundle
                return fragment
            }
}
```

---

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val newsPost = arguments?.getParcelable<NewsPost>(extraNewsPost)

}
```

Note - When passing it across activities, there is an extra layer of Sealed Classes going on, but it will crash as well if I simply tried to pass a NewsPost across activities, so the extra layer is not the issue.

This seems like it might be a bug with the Kotlin Parcelize feature.

Is there any reason why passing it across activities would throw an error but passing it between fragments doesn't?  If there is a reason... any suggestions on how I could pass this across activities?

Comment: So after all of that, I did realize I could just pass the ID of the newsPost in this one circumstance, and re-fetch it on the other side, so I have a workaround in the meantime, it just means I now have to handle the nullability potential on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md) clearly state:

> The primary constructor should be accessible (non-private)

Not sure why it's working when passing to fragment and not working when passing to activity.
In my case, I solved this issue by making my class constructor internal.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that documentation, @Evgeni! This tidbit should really be in the Compiler Plugin docs at kotlinlang.org. All I had found was [an article](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/a-study-of-the-parcelize-feature-from-kotlin-android-extensions-59a5adcd5909) that contradicts this and demonstrates the use of private constructors. In my case, the same code worked some of the time and threw this exception when returning from an external Activity. I didn't dig too far into it; I just implemented a custom Parceler (because I didn't want to expose the constructor). This works as well.